# How to save checkbox value in localStorage?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I'm stuck about saving checkbox value inside localStorage, I found some topics about here but I still get issue with.

Here is part of my **HTML** that creates the checkbox :

```
<div id="displayer_show">
    <div class="demo" id="labels2-3">
        <input name="switch_show" type="checkbox" value="1" checked/>
     </div>
</div>
```

And part of my **main** script :

```
$(function () {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("showning");
    if (data !== null) {
        $("input[name='switch_show']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});

$("input[name='switch_show']").click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("showning", $(this).val());
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("showning");
    }
});
```

There is jsfiddle link of it : http://jsfiddle.net/remibenault/Dp4Tj/8/

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Edit your script as following:

```
$(function () {
  var data = localStorage.showning;
  $("input[name='switch_show']")
    .prop('checked',data=='true')
    .change(function () {
       localStorage.showning = $(this).prop("checked");
    });
});
```

The problem is that checkbox is checked by default, and you

Comment: I tried your script inside jsfiddle and works fine but as @soktinpk answer, doesn't work on my script.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `value="1" checked` part and you're fine. Also `$(this).val()` should be `1`. I'm not quite sure why you're calling `$(this).val()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/Dp4Tj/9/

Comment: Oh thank you a lot, I'm new in Jquery and Javascript and I've still difficulties with. Mix several scripts don't work all the time =)